# Gurobi Function of Variables

Tags: java, gurobi

I have a function like this: `y = f(x) = a*(x/b) + c`

And I'd like to maximize `y` using Gurobi. Both `x` and `y` must be Gurobi Variables.

How can I model this problem?

P.S: `a`, `b` and `c` are numerical values.

Answer (score 3):

First you have to add both `x` and `y` as variables, e.g.

```
GRBVar x = model.addVar(0.0, GRB.INFINITY, 0.0, GRB.CONTINUOUS, "x");
GRBVar y = model.addVar(0.0, GRB.INFINITY, 0.0, GRB.CONTINUOUS, "y");
```

then set the objective function to maximize `y`

```
GRBLinExpr expr = new GRBLinExpr();
expr.addTerm(1.0, y);
model.setObjective(expr, GRB.MAXIMIZE);
```

and add a constraint stating that `y = a*(x/b) + c`, or equivalently `y - a/b * x = c`:

```
expr = new GRBLinExpr();
expr.addTerm(1.0, y); expr.addTerm(- a/b, x); 
model.addConstr(expr, GRB.EQUAL, c, "c0");
```

Alternatively, you can also set the objective by specifying the objective coefficient in the variable definition. I.e., replace the definition of `y` by

```
GRBVar y = model.addVar(0.0, GRB.INFINITY, 1.0, GRB.CONTINUOUS, "y");
```

The defintion of the objective then simply becomes

```
model.set(GRB.IntAttr.ModelSense, GRB.MAXIMIZE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add to Silke's Answer that you'll likely need to open up the range for the x and y variable so that they can be negative values, depending on the coefficients you're using.

Comment: would love feedback on why this is not useful